# Text (title) in PagerTitleStrip disappears after onPageSelected

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with a PagerTitleStrip which used to work as it should...

After updating to the latest support library (v4:23), the text in the PagerTitleStrip disappears after onPageSelected. The text is shown while I'm scrolling, but than disappears again when I let the page go and it "snaps in".

getPageTitle() returns the correct String.

This happens in two different Activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known AOSP issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183127

I got it working by downgrading support library to 22.2.1:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 22
        ...
    }

    ...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    ...
}
```